# Get specific data field from NSDictionarys nested in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, kvc

I have a array with nested dictionary data like this:

```
    [{ link : [
               { $ref: "foo", $href: "first_foo"},
               { $ref: "bar", $href: "barrrrrrr"},
               { $ref: "quz", $href: "quzzzzzzz"}]},
     { link : [
               { $ref: "foo", $href: "second_foo"},
               { $ref: "bar", $href: "barrrrrrr"},
               { $ref: "quz", $href: "quzzzzzzz"}]}]
```

I want to pick out the `foo` of each dictionary. The wanting result like this:

```
    [{ foo: "first_foo"}, { foo: "second_foo"}]
```

I've tried using `[myArray valueForKey @"@customFilterForFoo"]`, and implemented the `customFilterForFoo` for category on NSDictionary, but this ends up with `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFArray 0x6b81a10> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key customFilterForFoo.'`

How can i do something like this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to make it work ?

Comment: I've adopted your approach, though it's not that concise indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should loop in your array of dictionaries then in each one search for your foo's value :

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfFooValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *aDictionary in myArray) {
      if ([aDictionary valueForKey @"foo"]!= nil) {
           [arrayOfFooValues addObject:[aDictionary valueForKey @"foo"]];
      }
}
```

if you want your "wanting result" you can use the setValue:forKey: method but since the result is an array of Foo's values, key value coding isn't necessary in all cases (unless you want to add something else in your array)